# How to use conditional formatting on a Total sum of numbers in a column ? and change the value in red if any wrong value is entered manually?

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I need help with the conditional formatting in Excel,

```
February 19'
      11,820 
      135,271 
      32,233 
      810 
      0
      328 
Total: 180,462
```

I have the above column in my excel sheet, The total is the Sum of all the values in the upper columns , i need help only with the Total, Is there any way i could change the color of the value in total to RED if an incorrect value is manually entered, even though there is an existing formula to total the values.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you define as an incorrect value. Let's suppose a correct value is defined as: value is numeric.

In this case you can create a dummy verifying if each input is numeric and sum the total. Then create a conditional formatting rule comparing the sum of the dummies to the row count of your data and if it does not match then format the background red.

Example of formula in ColB: =if(isnumber(A2),1,0)

Conditional formatting formula: =$B$6<>rows($A$2:$A$5)

For example

```
          ColA   ColB
 row1     Feb_19 Dummy
 row2     20     1
 row3     30     1
 row4     40     1
 row5     three  0
 row6     90     3
```

Considering your clarification, if all you want is to verify that the value in the cell is truly the sum of all the values then you can do conditional formatting directly on the cell where you have the sum. Say the total value is located in A7, then your conditional formatting formula would be: =$A$7<>sum($A$1:$A$6)

Comment: Hi Miguelangel,

The numbers are always Numeric, there are no non numeric values entered, I was only concerned with the total value, i have a formula right now which totals up the numbers in the column and gives me the right count, no problem, but there are some times where we enter the total value manually for example using a external calculator, i just wanted the cell to be colored red in case if a wrong sum of values has been entered in the TOTAL

Answer (score 0):

Select the sum cell and then Go to

1. Conditional Formatting
2. Manage Rules
3. New Rule
4. Use Formula to determine which cells to format

Enter this formula

```
= A8 <> SUM(A2:A7)
```

and set the formatting you want to display if the value is not equal to sum

A8 is cell containing the sum, A2:A7 is the range containing the numbers